# Border and Flow Layout doesn't show two windows?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout, flowlayout

I created two method with parameters one as `BorderLayout` and other as `FlowLayout` and each method has its own frame.

But only one window popups with mix layout.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BLayOut extends JFrame
{
private JFrame fr,fr2;
private JLabel label,label2,label3;

public void win(BorderLayout bl)

{
fr =new JFrame("BorderLayout");

setSize(300,200);
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


setLayout(bl); 

label= new JLabel("Label 1");
label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
label3 = new JLabel("Label 2");
add(label,BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(label2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(label3,BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public void win(FlowLayout fl)
{
fr2 =new JFrame("FlowLayout");
setSize(500,200);
setVisible(true);
setLocation(300, 0);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


setLayout(fl); 

label= new JLabel("Label 1");
label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
label3 = new JLabel("Label 3");
add(label);
add(label2);
add(label3);

}


}

class BLayOutMain
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        BLayOut bl = new BLayOut();
        bl.win(new BorderLayout());
        bl.win(new FlowLayout());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up your references...

First, you create a class that extends from `JFrame`...

```
public class BLayOut extends JFrame {
```

Then you declare two instance variables of `JFrame`...

```
private JFrame fr, fr2;
```

Then in your methods, you create an instance of `JFrame` and assign it to one of these variables and promptly ignore them...

```
fr = new JFrame("BorderLayout");

// Which frame are you modifying now...??
setSize(300, 200);
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setLayout(bl);

label = new JLabel("Label 1");
label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
label3 = new JLabel("Label 2");
add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(label3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Basically, what this is doing is setting the properties of the instance of `BLayOut` and not `fr` or `fr2`.

Start by dropping the `extends JFrame` from `BLayOut`, it's confusing the issue, this will generate a list of compiler errors where the methods cannot be found.  These can be fixed by using either `fr` or `fr2`, depending on the method...

```
fr = new JFrame("BorderLayout");

// Which frame are you modifying now...??
fr.setSize(300, 200);
fr.setVisible(true);
fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

fr.setLayout(bl);

fr.label = new JLabel("Label 1");
fr.label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
fr.label3 = new JLabel("Label 2");
fr.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
fr.add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
fr.add(label3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You really should only call `setVisible` when you are ready to display the initialized UI

```
fr = new JFrame("BorderLayout");
//...
fr.setVisible(true);
```

This way, your UI will show up without having the need to `revalidate` the frame in some way...

Comment: OR i could jsut create another instance                          BLayOut bl = new BLayOut();
        BLayOut b2 = new BLayOut();
        bl.win(new BorderLayout());
        b2.win(new FlowLayout()); but don;t know is it a good idea.

Comment: @mhrzn I'm assuming that it's a test, so either way should be able to work, I just have a personal distaste for extending from `JFrame`